# How to change the default value of a function with another function?

Tags: php, function, default

```
function set_firstname($firstname){
// some code here
}
function fullname($lastname){
$firstname = set_firstname();
return $firstname." ".$lastname;
}
set_firstname("Rajesh");
echo fullname("Dhar");          // Rajesh Dhar
echo fullname("Basu");          // Rajesh Basu
echo fullname("Niyogi");        // Rajesh Niyogi
set_firstname("Sharmila");
echo fullname("Sen");           // Sharmila Sen
echo fullname("Chatterjee");    // Sharmila Chatterjee
echo fullname("Pal");           // Sharmila Pal
```

How should I define the function `set_firstname` so that the above code works properly?

Comment: Will anybody please tell me what the downvotes are for?

Comment: Though I didn't down-vote: A SO question must show efforts on your part (be it research or coding attempts) that show you've actually _tried_ to get what you need. You just show 2 functions, one is empty -apart from a `//code here` comment- and, basically, ask _"What code can I put here to do this"_... that doesn't show much in the way of efforts you may have undertaken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update:*
It would appear that you're looking for a way to influence/change a function's behaviour in the same way `date_default_timezone_set` influences the behaviour of `date` functions across the board. The answer to this is quite simple: you can't... not really. The functions you're thinking off don't actually *change* the other functions. They change the *runtime* (ini settings and the like), and it's that *runtime* that the other functions use to compute their respective return values.
Think of `date_default_timezone_set` as getting on an airplane: you can fly to a part of the world that is situated in a different timezone, and your biological clock will adapt (after a while) to that other timezone, you'll even set your clock differently. But your *house*, your birthday and all other things *don't change*. The place where you are at any given time is your *"runtime"*, and it is susceptible to changes. These changes may cause you to behave/react differently, but they don't actually change who you are...

using regular functions, you *could* use `static` variables:

```
function firstname($name = null)
{
    static $return = 'Default';
    $return = $name ? $name : $return;
    return $return;
}
function fullName($name)
{
    return firstname().' '.$name;
}
//test:
echo fullName('foobar');//echoes Default foobar
firstname('Mr. ');
echo fullName('foobar');//echoes Mr. foobar
```

But truth be told, that's *not* a good way to go about your business. It's hard to maintain, hard to read and error-prone. To be honest, if you need 2 bits of data that the user has to provide, there really is *nothing* wrong with asking the user for both values:

```
function fullName($first, $last)
{
    return $first.' '.$last;
}
```

But then, why use a function at all?
In more general terms, you're actually looking for a way to couple *state* to functionality. As luck would have it: classes do just that (couple data with methods). A *"better"* or more logical approach, then, would be:

```
class Name
{
    protected $firstName = null;
    protected $lastName = null;
    public function __construct($first = 'Default', $last = null)
    {
        $this->firstName = $first;
        $this->lastName = $last;
    }
    public function getFullName($last = null, $first = null)
    {
        if ($last) $this->lastName = $last;
        if ($first) $this->firstName = $first;
        return $first.' '.$last;
    }
}
```

The added benefit of classes here, though I didn't include this in my example, is that you can *check* the values that are being passed to the methods, and you can filter out invalid input. things like `is_string`, regex validation, `filter_var` calls and the like...
Add to that that, as your project grows, you can elaborate on a given class quite easily, like adding a `protected $email = null` property, along with a setter that performs `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` to make sure a valid email address is set, and you've got yourself a nice little data-container, that can hold all sorts of data related to *a person*, as it is represented in your DB, and used throughout the rest of your code.

Comment: My question is “How to change the default value of a function with another function?” I could have cited `date_default_timezone_set` or `imagesetthickness` as examples but ventured (foolishly, now I can see) to create my own examples so that nobody here flags my question on account of having no code. I promise that I’m not going to use functions like `set_firstname` or `fullname` _anywhere_ in my life.

Comment: @SoumalyoBardhan: The answer to that is simply: you can't. `date_default_timezone_set` doesn't change the return value of any of the `date` functions. It changes a setting of the runtime, from which other functions get the data they need to _produce_ their output. The dependant functions return the result of a computation, the input for this computation is extracted from a combination of system settings + ini settings. It's those `ini`'s that you can alter, the functions themselves remain the same. The closest you can get is `ReflectionClass` instances

Comment: @SoumalyoBardhan: edited my answer, explaining what the difference is between user-defined functions and functions that use the runtime to return given values

Answer (score 1):

```
function set_firstname($name = "") {
    static $_name;
    if($name != "") {
        $_name = $name;
    } else {
        return $_name;
    }
}
```

Altough I have to admit, that this is really bad coding style. (my opinion)

Comment: Why do you call it “really bad coding style”? I think the functions like `date_default_timezone_set` and `imagesetthickness` are structured in similar ways.

Comment: I myself prefer classes because we then make clear that it may contain variables. A function instead should not store anything, but this is just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You must use classes, in which you can store variable that belong to that class. For example,

```
class Person
{
    protected $_Firstname;
    protected $_Lastname;

    public function __construct($firstname, $lastname)
    {
        // set the initial first- and lastname
        $this->_Firstname = $firstname;
        $this->_Lastname = $lastname;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return sprinft("%s %s", $this->_Firstname, $this->_Lastname);
    }

    public function SetFirstname($value)
    {
        $this->_Firstname = $value;
    }
}

// create a new instance of a person
$p = new Person("Rajesh", "Dhar");

echo $p; // will display: "Rasjeh Dhar"

$p->SetFirstname("Sharmila");

echo $p; // will display: "Sharmila Dhar"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$first_name = '';

function set_firstname($firstname){
    global $first_name;
    $first_name = $firstname;
}

function fullname($lastname){
    global $first_name;
    return $first_name ." ".$lastname;
}
```

Comment: You are forgetting to use 'global' in both functions.

Comment: Yeah. Fixed. Thank you for notify.

Comment: Ouch... I've stated, in my answer, how `static` is a bad idea already... using `global` is, IMHO, even worse: if the variable is global already, why would you even bother using the `fullname` function, and not simply use `$fullname = $first_name.' '.$lastname;` without calling a function?